# Sort a column within groups in Pandas

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

I am new to pandas. I'm trying to sort a column within each group. So far, I was able to group first and second column values together and calculate the mean value in third column. But I am still struggling to sort 3rd column.

[This is my input dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufHgo.jpg)
[This is my dataframe after applying groupby and mean function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsLpA.jpg)

I used the following line of code to group input dataframe,
    df_o=df.groupby(by=['Organization Group','Department']).agg({'Total Compensation':np.mean})

Please let me know how to sort the last column for each group in 1st column using pandas.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
#for return df add parameter as_index=False
df_o=df.groupby(['Organization Group','Department'], 
                 as_index=False)['Total Compensation'].mean()
df_o = df_o.sort_values(['Total Compensation','Organization Group'])
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Organization Group':['a','b','a','a'],
                   'Department':['d','f','a','a'],
                   'Total Compensation':[1,8,9,1]})

print (df)
  Department Organization Group  Total Compensation
0          d                  a                   1
1          f                  b                   8
2          a                  a                   9
3          a                  a                   1

df_o=df.groupby(['Organization Group','Department'], 
                as_index=False)['Total Compensation'].mean()
print (df_o)
  Organization Group Department  Total Compensation
0                  a          a                   5
1                  a          d                   1
2                  b          f                   8

df_o = df_o.sort_values(['Total Compensation','Organization Group'])
print (df_o)
  Organization Group Department  Total Compensation
1                  a          d                   1
0                  a          a                   5
2                  b          f                   8
```

Comment: I am getting following error"KeyError: 'Organization Group'"

Comment: I want the output to be in following format                                                                                                            Organization_group  Department   Total Compensation                                   a                                a                              5                                                      no val                        d                              1                                                        b                               f                              8